# AWS JavaScript/Nodejs Comprehend PII client isn't await-able?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I am using AWS Comprehend's "PII" detection tools to spot personally identifying information (PII) in arbitrary text submitted by the public.

This is for a Nodejs Lambda that I mean to run in our AWS account.

```
const {Comprehend} = require('@aws-sdk/client-comprehend'); 
const client = new Comprehend({ region: "us-east-2" });   

module.exports.handler = async (event, _context) => {    
    const message = event.data;
    var redactedMessage = await getRedactedMessage(message);    
    return redactedMessage;
}

const getRedactedMessage = async (message) => {
   
    // the Comprehend PII system takes strings up to 4000 characters
    // so we split it on word boundaries after 4000 chars or less.
    var messageParts = message.match(/.{1,4000}(\s|$)/g);  
    var redactedString = "";
    
    for (const part in messageParts) {
         try {
            const checkPart = {
                Text : message,
                LanguageCode : "en"
            };

            client.detectPiiEntities(checkPart, function (err, pii) {
                console.log("Why does this come last?");
            });            

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } finally {
            console.log("Why do I get here first?");
        }

        console.log("And here? Then suddenly...");
    }
    
}
```

No matter what, the output is

```
Why do I get here first?
And here? Then suddenly...
Why does this come last?
```

I have littered this with every possible combination of "async" and "await" commands.  I have rewritten the `client.detectPiiEntities(checkPart, function (err, pii)...` line like a promise with a `.then()` but no matter what, I can't make it wait for the results of `client.detectPiiEntities` block.

I'm sure it's something dumb.  (Probably me.)  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are clearly using a callback based API, not a promise-based one. Is there a promise-based equivalent for the API you are using?

Comment: Thanks @Evert, but so far, no...I can't find any alternative like that.  I have made comparable code work in .NET Core.  There I can do either `DetectPiiEntities()` or `.DetectPiiEntitiesAsync()` and both work as expected.

Comment: Typically you can obtain a promise in the AWS SDK by doing something like `client.detectPiiEntities(checkPart).promise()`. Usually that returns something that is awaitable.

Comment: Thanks, Evert - but no, the `.promise()` caused errors so I presume it's not available here.

Comment: You gotta give me more than that. 'caused errors?' what kind of errors?